# Proper way to add GestureDector to Listview.builder card in Flutter?

Tags: navigation, widget, flutter, gesturedetector

I have an Expanded widget wrapped around a `Listview.builder` of Card. How can I make my card not only detect `onTap` but also pass variables to my new `.dart` file on Navigation. I'm currently getting a sizing error?

**Updated With Code**

Here is my code:

```
new Expanded(
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: id == null ? 0 : id.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return new Card(
                        child: new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Image.network(video[index]),
                            new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(3.0)),
                            new Text(title[index],
                            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            new GestureDetector(onTap: (){
                              print(id[index]);
                            },)

                          ],
                        ),
                      );

                    }))
```

Here is the thrown exception:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout.
This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
```

I would like to pass `title[index]` and `video[index]` similar to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in iOS Swift.

Comment: Can you clarify this part please "pass variables to my new .dart", also it would be better if you add code to be able to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @aziza  I've added the my code and thrown error exception.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are adding the `GestureDetector` as one child of the `Column`, and Flutter does not understand what piece of UI this `GestureDetector` needs to be detecting different touch events on (you are not specifying where exactly do you need this `GestureDetector` to be performing its task)

**If you need the whole `Card` to be interactive, you need to wrap your `Card` within a `GestureDecetor` as follows**

```
var id = ["title 1", "title 2", "title 3", "title 4", "title 5",];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: id == null ? 0 : id.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new GestureDetector( //You need to make my child interactive
              onTap: () => print(id[index]),
              child: new Card( //I am the clickable child
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //new Image.network(video[index]),
                    new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(3.0)),
                    new Text(id[index],
                      style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),


                  ],
                ),),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This helped me on my custom listView ;)

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Similar to aziza's suggestion you could have a look at [InkWell](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) which basically is a GestureDetector but has the material design splash.

You also asked about how to pass variables to another class. You can do that by just handing them over in your instantiation as constructor variables. Have a look at the onTap method in the code example.

Code could look like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    body: new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: id == null ? 0 : id.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return new OtherClass(id[index], video[index]);
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          child: new Card(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                //new Image.network(video[index]),
                new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(3.0)),
                new Text(id[index],
                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
  );
}
```

*Code not tested

Comment: This solution worked for me better than the accepted one because with `GestureDetector` my `ListView` items (which are not `Card`s, but `Container`s) are not tappable on empty areas

Comment: @JuliánMartínez You can set hitTestBehaviour to translucent so that it detects tap on empty areas too on Gesture Detector.